# Como saber se uma coluna existe numa tabela do SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou tentando adicionar uma nova coluna numa tabela de SQL Server, e quero saber se ela já existe ou não. Tenho tentado algo assim:

```sql
IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'minhaTabela' 
            AND  COLUMN_NAME = 'minhaColuna')
```

Mas sempre resolve como falso.

Como que posso saber se uma coluna já existe numa tabela do SQL Server?

Comment: Você pode só tentar inserir, se ela já existir simplesmente vai dar um erro.

Comment: @Havenard é verdade, mas quero um meio de adicionar se não estiver lá, mas se estiver, faz nada. Assim não dará erro, e poderei aplicar o script várias vezes e sempre sairá da mesma forma (com a coluna).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A *system view* `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` é especifica para cada banco. Adicione o nome do banco para garantir que você está checando no banco correto.  Dependendo do *collation* do banco, outro possível problema é com a caixa (maiúsculas/minusculas).

Tente o seguinte:

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM MEUBANCO.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            WHERE UPPER(TABLE_NAME) = UPPER('minhaTabela') 
            AND  UPPER(COLUMN_NAME) = UPPER('minhaColuna'))
```

Answer (score 9):

Para saber se a coluna já existe, pensei na seguinte solução, com `count`:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) AS resultado FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'minhaTabela' AND  COLUMN_NAME = 'minhaColuna'
```

No meu entendimento, isso retornará 0 se a coluna não existir, e 1 se existir. Tente adaptar alguma coisa  baseado nesse exemplo :)

**EDIT**: Achei um outro exemplo:

```sql
DECLARE @retorno int

SELECT @retorno = COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'minhaTabela' AND  COLUMN_NAME = 'minhaColuna'

IF (@retorno > 0)
BEGIN
    --Tem a tabela
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --Não tem a tabela
END
```

Answer (score 5):

Desta maneira, se pesquisa o nome da coluna em todas as tabelas do Schema.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'NomeColuna'
```

Answer (score 4):

Uma maneira simples que achei é verificando o 'cumprimento' (length em inglês) da coluna - pois a função volta NULL se a coluna não existe. (Isto é para SQL Server 2005+)

```
USE meuBanco
GO

IF ( COL_LENGTH( 'minhaTabela', 'minhaColuna' ) IS NOT NULL )
BEGIN

  -- Coluna existe

END
ELSE
BEGIN

  -- Coluna não existe

END
```

Answer (score 4):

Tente isto, funciona par aSQL Server 2008+ e muda pouca coisa para versões anteriores.

```
 if exists(
  select *
  from sys.sysobjects so
  join sys.syscolumns sc on sc.id = so.id
  where so.xtype = N'U'
  and so.name like N'tb%'
  and sc.name like N'id%'
 )
 print 'EXISTE!'
 else
 print 'NON ECXISTEEEE!'
```

de quebra você pode usar este select sempre que estiver procurando por colunas/tabelas no seu schema