# if dentro de show mysql para criar ou inserir

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, if

boa tarde, preciso entender como funciona um if dentro de mysql para poder utilizar da seguinte forma.

tenho um foreach que só executa depois de um select de banco de dados pois dele sai um array para este foreach, neste foreach ele irá rodar uma condição, caso uma coluna exista ele irá inserir informação nela, caso ela não exista ele irá criar a coluna e depois inserir informação na mesma, o problema é, se eu enviar duas colunas de mesmo nome ele irá criar a primeira e inserir já na segunda irá gerar erro pois a coluna existe, como ver se a coluna existe antes de criar sem ter que fazer outra consulta e outro loop?

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name = 'telefone' AND TABLE_NAME = 'usr_9f8b498a8e2976d3'

SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'usr_9f8b498a8e2976d3' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'telefone'
```

nestes dois selects eu consigo trazer se existe ou não a coluna, o de baixo é mais rápido, no caso, gostaria de no final destes selects, na mesma consulta, se der TRUE não criar a coluna mas se der false então criar a coluna

mais ou menos assim
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3774/8939

algo como isso, só que em mysql que funcione

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'usr_9f8b498a8e2976d3' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'telefone') THEN
BEGIN
        select * from usr_9f8b498a8e2976d3
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    select * from usr_9f8b498a8e2976d3
END;
END IF;
```

achei este código que é exatamente como quero, porém não consigo executar comando de alter table e ou insert into dentro do true e do false, mas true e false funcionam exatamente como desejo, existe como rodar alter tabble dentro do true e insert into dentro do false? no caso no false tem que rodar tanto alter table e o insert into e no true só o insert into

```
SELECT IF((SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'usr_9f8b498a8e2976d3' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'sobrenome'),(
'true'
),(
'false'
))
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54609/discussion-on-question-by-flourigh-if-dentro-de-show-mysql-para-criar-ou-inserir)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

procurando e muito, muito mesmo, muitos testes, achei uma alternativa, mas ainda não a que desejo

```
SET @preparedStatement = (SELECT IF((
SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$usr_' AND COLUMN_NAME = '" . acent_remove($value) . "'
) > 0,
' ',
'ALTER TABLE $usr_ ADD " . acent_remove($value) . " VARCHAR(99) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL'
));
PREPARE alterIfNotExists FROM @preparedStatement;
EXECUTE alterIfNotExists;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE alterIfNotExists;
```

esta opção funciona porém não sei como por apas dentro da aspa pois ele presisa que o alter table fique entre ' ' e eu preciso rodar ' ' ' '

```
"ALTER TABLE $usr_ ADD " . acent_remove($value) . " VARCHAR(99) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '" . $array_form_a_index[$index] . "'"
```

no final deste trecho '" . $array_form_a_index[$index] . "' preciso que ele entenda a aspa do comentário sem afetar a aspa dupla pois está dentro de php com PDO, complicado

```
$statement = $conect -> prepare("SET @preparedStatement = (SELECT IF((
SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$usr_' AND COLUMN_NAME = '" . acent_remove($value) . "'
) > 0,
' ',
'ALTER TABLE $usr_ ADD " . acent_remove($value) . " VARCHAR(99) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL'));
PREPARE alterIfNotExists FROM @preparedStatement;
EXECUTE alterIfNotExists;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE alterIfNotExists; ");
```

não sei exatamente se em termos de velocidade e ou outros termos técnico esta seria a melhor forma, mas heredoc está dando erro de sintax então descobri como "escapar string" e agora está funcionando bem

segue código finalizado

```
$statement = $conect -> prepare("SET @preparedStatement = (SELECT IF((
SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$usr_' AND COLUMN_NAME = '" . acent_remove($value) . "') > 0,
' ',
'ALTER TABLE $usr_ ADD " . acent_remove($value) . " VARCHAR(99) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT \'" . $array_form_a_index[$index] . "\''
));
PREPARE alterIfNotExists FROM @preparedStatement;
EXECUTE alterIfNotExists;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE alterIfNotExists;");
```

se alguém souber como fazer isso de forma correta ou se assim é o correto, aceito sugestões. grato